# I am able to view the count of delete votes in timeline view (without having 10k rep)

Tags: support, timeline

When I visit the [timeline view](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51532659/timeline) of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51532659/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-tolocaleuppercase-of-undefined, I see the following:

[image]

Given that I don't have 10k reputation, I cannot cast delete votes yet. I believe I shouldn't be able to view the delete vote count as well.

Also, from what I recall, I never had the ability to view the count of delete votes in the timeline view. So if any rules haven't changed recently, this seems to be a bug!?

---

For reference, here's what I see in an incognito tab (i.e. without logging in):

[image]

This makes sense because anonymous users can't see vote breakdown, i.e. the count of Up and Down votes separately.

---

### Update:

Considering the suggestion in the [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371601/i-am-able-to-view-the-count-of-delete-votes-in-timeline-view-without-having-10k?noredirect=1#comment614511_371601) and [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371624/5894241) that delete votes might be visible because they are "public" information, I decided to look at other sites where I have less than 1k reputation.

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/19281/is-fever-any-good) question on SuperUser which has two delete votes [according to the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#fromdate=2009-08-05&todate=2009-08-07&order=desc&max=-3&sort=votes&filter=!-*jbN-_OiwRb&site=superuser&run=true) <sup>[(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1uDR.png)</sup>. However I don't see the delete votes in the [timeline view](https://superuser.com/posts/19281/timeline):

[image]

So it seems a bit strange to see delete votes, but not close votes, if both of them are considered public information.<sup>(1)</sup>

<sup>1: For example, [this question](https://superuser.com/posts/1343201/timeline) has 1 close vote according to the API, but it cannot be seen on the timeline view.</sup>

Comment: Hi, <1k here . I don't see delete vote. I could be  1k<rep<10k issue.

Comment: Perhaps this is related to the `see vote count` privilege you unlock at 1k rep? Not sure if Delete votes count as votes in that context, though (the established user info page doesn't mention them).

Comment: @Codeer I don't think so. Also, I have had that privilege for over a year, but I don't recall ever seeing the delete votes before.

Comment: Doesn't seem harmful though, it would become a problem if you can cast delete votes. But being able to see how many are cast is just input you can use to decide to not do anything with the content, since its likely going to disappear soon. If this is unintented, I would vote for it to stay.

Comment: I don't see an issue in you being able to see these, but whatever is causing it if it is a bug may effect other stuff

Comment: first time I see that timeline! where is the link to access this? or should I manually build it using the Question ID?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I use [a userscript](https://stackapps.com/a/4238/49077) for that.

Comment: I've got 8700 rep, both of those links are 404 for me.

Comment: @Draco18s that's because you don't have 10k to see deleted posts.

Comment: @Braiam Ah, I misunderstood the scenario, as the Asker *doesn't have 10k either,* but what changed was that the post went from "having delete votes" to "deleted."

Comment: Counts for delete-, close-, up-, and down-votes are not considered private information. They are publicly available though the SE API and, other than close-vote counts, are available in the timeline.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't any privilege for seeing delete vote counts. You can see your own post delete vote count, if there were any. The only privilege is to see your own post vote count is for the close votes and the up/down breakdown.

The only privilege for delete votes is about casting them.

Comment: That does make sense but doesn't explain why they don't appear on the anonymous view. Also, by your theory, users with <3k rep should be able to view the count of close votes. I would try that on one of the other sites.

Comment: I have updated the question based on what I found. Also, are you suggesting that viewing close vote count is a privilege but viewing delete vote count is not? That seems a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: @NisargShah The close-vote count is not reported in the timeline. Nobody sees it there. No event is recorded in the timeline for close-votes until the post is closed, then you can see the usernames. No indication that the question is in the close-vote queue is shown on the timeline until the question is no longer in the CV queue. Close-votes/close-vote count information is only available in the "close" button under the question and in the close-vote dialog. The counts of delete-, close-, up-, and down-votes are available from the SE API, which does not require you to be logged-in to access.