# Partially formatted "Similar Questions" panel on "Ask" page

Tags: bug, asking-questions

As I was asking my [previous question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371601/i-am-able-to-view-the-count-of-delete-votes-in-timeline-view-without-having-10k), this "Similar Questions" panel popped up, but it doesn't seem to be formatted according to the new "site-wide" style (i.e. no padding, no separate header section etc).

[image]

OS: Windows 10, Chrome 67.0.3396.99

---

For reference, here's how other panels on the same page look like:

[image]

I'm assuming this is not [status-by-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-by-design).

Comment: You might as well include your OS and broswer details here

Comment: Reproed in Chromium Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build), Linux